# Number of passengers on a bus/Departuring busses in Poisson process problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

> Buses leave a bus station according to  a Poisson process 
>   $\{B_t\}$ of rate $\lambda$, while travellers reach the same station according to (an independent) Poisson process $\{T_t\}$ of rate $\mu$. Travellers get on the bus and leave the station as soon as a bus departures.
>
> $(1)$ Let $N$ be the random variable, expressing the number of passengers on a departuring bus. Find $P(N=k),~k=0,1,2,\ldots$
>
> $(2)$ Let $\Lambda$ be the random variable, expressing the number of  departuring buses till the time the $1000$th traveller has reached the station. Find $P(\Lambda=k),~k=0,1,2,\ldots$

**Attempt**.

(1) In order for $N$ to be $k$ there must be $k$ travellers reaching the bus station and no bus leaving in between. The time needed for k travellers to reach the station is $W\sim Gamma(k,\mu)$, so $$P(N=k)=P(B_W=0)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}P(B_w=0)f_W(w)dw=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\lambda w} \frac{\mu^k}{(k-1)!}w^{k-1}e^{-\mu w}dw.$$

(2) The time needed for the $1000$th traveller to reach the station is $W\sim Gamma(1000,\mu)$, so $$P(\Lambda=k)=P(B_W=k)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}P(B_w=k)f_W(w)dw=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\lambda w}\frac{(\lambda w)^k}{k!} \frac{\mu^{1000}}{999!}w^{999}e^{-\mu w}dw.$$

Am I on the right path? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sake of completeness I post my answer, based on the useful remarks made by @Furrer:

(1) $$P(N\geq k)=P(B_W=0)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\lambda w} \frac{\mu^k}{(k-1)!}e^{-\mu w}dw=\Big(\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}\Big)^k$$
and $$P(N=k)=P(N\geq k)-P(N\geq k+1)=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}~\Big(1-\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}\Big)^k$$ 
(geometric distribution)

(2) $$P(\Lambda= k)=P(B_W=k)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\lambda w}\frac{(\lambda w)^k}{k!} \frac{\mu^{1000}}{999!}w^{999}e^{-\mu w}dw=\binom{999+k}{k}\Big(\frac{\lambda}{\mu+\lambda}\Big)^k\Big(1-\frac{\lambda}{\mu+\lambda}\Big)^{1000}.$$

**Question**: if I have to plug in numbers for $\lambda,~\mu$, they have to be on the same time unit, for example both rates expressed in days, or both in months?

Comment: Yes - the parameters would have to be in the same time unit. 

Some explanation:
After all $W$ is constructed as the "time needed for $k$ travellers to reach the station" while say $B_t$ is the number of busses that have left the train at time $t$. Thus if $\lambda$ is $5$ per hour, you are stating that at average 5 busses leave each hour. Then $\mathbb{E}[B_t]=5t$ - this only makes sense, if $t$ measures time in hours. And thus $W$ has to be a time in hours, requiring $T_t$ to have a rate in per hours.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part:
At time $W\sim \Gamma(k,\mu)$, $k$ travellers have arrived to the bus station. Thus we know that if $B_W = 0$, then at least $k$ passengers will leave with the first bus*. So you are really evaluating $P(N\geq k)$. Your final integral in (1) should be easily computed by recognising what looks like the density of another gamma distribution.
To generalise the thinking from the 'first bus' to 'a bus', it is of course important that a Poisson process $L$ satisfies, that $L(t)-L(s)$ is equal in distribution to $L(t-s)$ and that it is independent of $L(l)_{l\leq s}$. Just have this in mind: Showing it for the first bus is enough.

For the second part:
Seems all fine.

*: Maybe some additional considerations should be given to this, after all the Poisson processes only have càdlàg sample paths.

Comment: Thank you Furrer. So, for the first part, you are saying that (1) $P(N\geq k)=P(B_W=0)$ and $P(N=k)=P(N\geq k)-P(N\geq k+1)$ - the evaluation should go for each probability or straight for the above difference? And (2) working for a bus is the same as working for "a" bus.

Comment: (1): I would evaluate $P(N\geq k)=P(B_W=0)=\int_0^\infty P(B_w=0)f_W(w)dw$ and then at the end calculate $P(N=k)=P(N\geq k) - P(N \geq k+1)$.
(2): Exactly.

Comment: (2): When considering $B_W$ you are considering the 'first bus'. This is the same as considering 'a bus' by the argument I gave. If $W_1,W_2,...$ denotes the waiting times between each $k$ passengers arriving, i.e. $T_{W_1}=k$, $T_{W_2}=2k$ etc., then it can be shown that $P(B_{W_{i+1}}-B_{W_{i}}=0)=P(B_{W_1}=0)$. Thus whether you consider the 'first bus' or 'a bus' does not matter.